# how to push a new Card onto a StackNavigator in react-navigation without animation?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to push a new screen onto a StackNavigator, but without animation. I need the effect to be instant. I'm looking through the docs, but I'm having a hard time discerning how to configure the transition for a `StackNavigator`. I only need do disable animation for one specific route.

In the StackNavigatorConfig section of [this page](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack) I see some config objects outlined such as `transitionConfig` that seem potentially promising..? but how do I find a description of how to use these objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [issue 1120](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1120), currently animation cannot be disabled.

And transitionConfig is not well documented, its definition can be found [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/blob/master/src/TypeDefinition.js#L417)

```
export type NavigationTransitionSpec = {
  duration?: number,
  // An easing function from `Easing`.
  easing?: (t: number) => number,
  // A timing function such as `Animated.timing`.
  timing?: (value: AnimatedValue, config: any) => any,
};

/**
 * Describes a visual transition from one screen to another.
 */
export type TransitionConfig = {
  // The basics properties of the animation, such as duration and easing
  transitionSpec?: NavigationTransitionSpec,
  // How to animate position and opacity of the screen
  // based on the value generated by the transitionSpec
  screenInterpolator?: (props: NavigationSceneRendererProps) => Object,
};
```

Example FYI:

```
  // custom Modal transition animation
  transitionConfig: () => ({
    transitionSpec: {
      duration: 250,
      easing: Easing.out(Easing.poly(4)),
      timing: Animated.timing,
    },
    screenInterpolator: sceneProps => {
      const { layout, position, scene } = sceneProps
      const { index } = scene

      const height = layout.initHeight
      const translateY = position.interpolate({
        inputRange: [index - 1, index, index + 1],
        outputRange: [height, 0, 0],
      })

      const opacity = position.interpolate({
        inputRange: [index - 1, index - 0.99, index],
        outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
      })

      return { opacity, transform: [{ translateY }] }
    },
  }),
```